# Quadratic Space

Tags: linear-algebra

B) Let r ∈ R be a real number, and consider the quadratic space (R^2, ϕr)
where ϕr is the given in the standard basis by the matrix
Ar =
\begin{pmatrix}2 & r \\ r & -3\end{pmatrix}
.
(1) Show that ϕr is non degenerate.

(2) Determine the set of vectors $v ∈ R^2$
such that $ϕr(v, v) = 0.$

(3) Find a basis $(v_1, v_2)$ of $R^2$
such that $ϕr(v_1, v_1) = ϕr(v_2, v_2) = 0$

So B(1) was easy, and for B (2) i got a function $f(y_1)$ for $x_1$ and $f(y_2)$ for $x_2$ , so I got $2$ vectors
\begin{pmatrix}(y(-r + \sqrt{(r^2 + 6})))/2 \\ y\end{pmatrix}
and \begin{pmatrix}(y(-r - \sqrt{(r^2 + 6)}))/2 \\ y\end{pmatrix}

But I don't know if this is the right way to show the set of vectors. And maybe someone can give me a hint for B(3) ? I mean can't I use my two vectors from above to get a basis ?
Thanks for help !

Comment: I edited for math formatting.  Please check that I did not change your meaning.